# Why is 'umount' not spelled 'unmount'?

Tags: history, unmounting

I am wondering if there is any historical or practical reason why the `umount` command is not `unmount`.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This dates all the way back to the [very first edition of Unix](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/umount), where all the standard file names were only at most 6 characters long (think `passwd`), even though this version supported a whooping [8 characters in a file name](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/5/directory). Most commands had an associated source file ending in `.c` (e.g. `umount.c`), which left only 6 characters for the base name.

A 6-character limitation might also have been a holdover from an earlier development version, or inherited from a then-current IBM system that did have a 6-character limitation. (Early C implementations had a 6-character limit on identifiers — longer identifiers were accepted but the compiler only looked at the first 6 characters, so `foobar1` and `foobar2` were the same variable.)

(I thought I remembered a `umount` man page that listed the spelling as a bug of unknown origin, but I can't find it now.)

Comment: 6 character command name + `.c` (or `.s`) extension = 8 character filename limit.

Comment: @geekosaur: Ah, right, the source file. If you write an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: Enh, just annotate it if you want.

Comment: @geekosaur: I thought of the man page, as well, but V1 didn't have a man command (and one of the man pages is called `directory`, which wouldn't have fit yet). So I wonder why `passwd` was truncated to 6 characters (there wasn't a `passwd` command yet either, just `/etc/passwd`).

Comment: Then why not use `unmt`? Sounds easier to remember.

Comment: Maybe it is because of the Greek οὐ suffix, which means "not", that would also explain `urandom`

Comment: Filenames and filename length limits actually have nothing whatsoever to do with this (and besides on early unix the limit was 14 characters).

Comment: @GregA.Woods Unix v1 did have an 8-character limit, the 14-character limit came a little later and then stayed for a while.

Comment: Well, since nothing before the 4th Edition had a kernel written in C, I'm not sure you can really rely on any pre-V4 naming conventions or limits within those earlier versions that might influence them either, though there was clearly some carry-over in syscall names.  In any case this has nothing whatsoever to do with filename lengths and everything to do with external identifiers stored in symbol tables and used in tools like assemblers and linkers (some of which would not have been the Unix implementations).

Comment: I will forever use `whooping` rather than `whopping` ;) Please don't edit that.

Answer (score 12):

It seems there's been some mis-information sitting here for a while now.

The most likely reason for the `umount` command having the abbreviated name is because it follows from the name of the system call which it uses:  `umount()`.

The probable reason the "unmount" system call having the name `umount()` is because early linkers limited the length of external identifiers to as few as 6 characters (of just one case) on some types of systems (and it made sense to maintain compatibility with such tools at the time), and "umount" is a logical form of abbreviation for "unmount".  See page 179 of the first edition of [*The C Programming Language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) for a list of the external identifier characteristics of various systems of interest at the time of publication.

Note also that early C compilers treated the first 8 characters of an identifier as significant, but allowed identifiers to be longer. (K&R page 33)

Note that the length of identifiers in symbol tables has *nothing* whatsoever to do directly with filename length, at least not within Unix (Unix symbol tables, since V1, have 8 characters for identifiers, though it is noted in the V1 manual that the assembler ["*generates symbols of at most 7 bytes*"](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/5/a.out)).

Answer (score -1):

For the same reason the `creat` system call is  not spelled `create` ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713457/what-did-ken-thompson-mean-when-he-said-id-spell-create-with-an-e

Comment: Nope. The regret in the quote you reference is because they could have added the 'e' even in spite of the 6 character limit being argued over in the other answer. There really is no good reason for it to be truncated, unlike with umount.

Comment: I'm guessing by that time it was tradition to truncate letters if you could.